# CSS - Improve tabs folding - position sticky

Tags: tabs, sticky

I'm trying to create tabs that stack over each other when the user scrolls. I use position: sticky to do this. It works pretty well, but I'd like to achieve two things.

The first thing is that I want to start moving the next card after the previous card sticks up. That is, once the first card touches the top, only then will the second card start moving. Until then, it waits stuck at the bottom like it is now in the demo. Similarly, the third card will only start moving after the second card touches the top.

The second thing I want to achieve is to make the cards appear in the order 1,2,3. Currently it's in order 3,2,1. I've tried changing it with z-index and rearranging it differently, but I haven't figured it out. In the demo I have a representation of what I would like to achieve at the end.

Can you please advise me on how to do this? Will I get by with just CSS, or will I have to use javascript?

Complete DEMO: https://codepen.io/mw3s/pen/jOdBNzO

```
<div class="tabs-container">
    <div class="tab">
        <span>1</span>
        <div class="tab-content">..</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <span>2</span>
        <div class="tab-content">..</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <span>3</span>
        <div class="tab-content">..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.tab {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```